# Render DESCRIPTION file to html

Tags: r, cran

I'm looking for a function which could be used to get exact or similar website to CRAN package html websites, for example this one: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html
I can use

```
utils::packageDescription("DBI")
```

in R to print the DESCRIPTION. I can start to work with strings from here and try to format it into html, but I know there are quite a lot of useful technical helpers in `utils` and other packages, so maybe there is something I could utilize to render DESCRIPTION into html?
The *Downloads* and *Reverse dependencies* sections are not as necessary in the html output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define the markup you desire or expect.

[CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries) has been doing this for close to a decade -- below is the code for a 'new' package. I just parse the `DESCRIPTION` file and then loop over it, setting the fields in bold and the value in normal text.

```
writeNewBlogEntry <- function(curPkg, curVer, reposurl) {
    blogpost <- file.path(blogInputDir, "new", 
                          paste(curPkg, "_", curVer, ".txt", sep=""))
    con <- file(blogpost, "wt")
    cat("New package", curPkg, "with initial version", curVer,"\n\n", file=con)
    dcf <- read.dcf( url(getDescriptionUrl(curPkg, reposurl)) )
    for (i in 1:ncol(dcf)) {
        cat("<strong>", colnames(dcf)[i], "</strong>: ",
            htmlEscape(dcf[1,i]), "<br>\n", sep="", file=con)
    }
    closeBlogPost(con, reposurl, curPkg)
}
```

This is old code, and it is in the context of the particular (static) text to html/rss renderer I use.